# Node version updated but not switching, still showing old version

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to update my node version, which is on `v16.20.2`.

I followed [this](https://medium.com/macoclock/update-your-node-js-on-your-mac-in-2020-948948c1ffb2) guide to update the version.

```
% sudo n lts
Password:
     copying : node/18.17.1
   installed : v18.17.1 to /usr/local/bin/node
      active : v16.20.2 at /opt/homebrew/opt/node@16/bin/node
% node -v   
v16.20.2
```

Looks like the version is provisioned but not switched. I checked on web if there is a way to do that, but no luck.

Comment: Why you shouldn't use NVM as a node version manager? That is easier to switch between the multiple node version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your desired Node.js version has been installed, you can select it by running the following command:

% sudo n use lts

You may need to check and verify the PATH environment variable in your shell config file:

export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"